# Kendo grid : Uncaught ReferenceError: Unit is not defined

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid, telerik

I created a kendo grid with a class as model. 
For a column, I set a ClientTemplate to get a property from a complex object linked to my class. It's working pretty well, I can see my column with the right data in.
But when I try to create a new row in my grid, I get this error :

```
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Unit is not defined
at eval (eval at compile (kendo.all.js:194), <anonymous>:3:271)
at init._rowsHtml (kendo.all.js:56572)
at init._renderContent (kendo.all.js:57216)
at init.refresh (kendo.all.js:57066)
at init.proxy (jquery.js:492)
at init.trigger (kendo.all.js:124)
at init._process (kendo.all.js:7271)
at init._change (kendo.all.js:7231)
at init.proxy (jquery.js:492)
at init.trigger (kendo.all.js:124)`
```

My grid column is defined like that :

```
.Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
                columns.Bound(p => p.Unit.Name).ClientTemplate(("#=Unit ? Unit.Name: ''#")).Title(Global.Unit);
                columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
            })
```

So in my grid, when there is a Unit linked to my item, it's displaying the Name of the Unit in the column. This part works.
But I can't create new rows, and I don't know why.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found what to do, if it can help someone :

On the grid parameters, in Model section, just add a default value to the field :

```
.Model(model => {
                    model.Id(p => p.Id);
                    model.Field(p => p.Unit).DefaultValue(new Unit());
                })
```